# Redirect full website address to another address - Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect the following via a virtual host:

```
http://www.surveys.abc.com/index.php?sid=14414&newtest=Y&lang=en
```

to

```
http://www.abc.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use Apache's mod_rewrite for that.

You can tweak your PHP code in index.php to look for those appropriate values in $_GET and then do the PHP redirect like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['sid']) && ($_GET['sid']==14414) && isset($_GET['newtest']) && ($_GET['newtest']==Y) && isset($_GET['lang']) && ($_GET['lang']=="en") ) {
      header( 'Location: http://www.abc.com' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've just implemented your suggestion. Although I was hoping for a rewrite solution via Apache.

Comment: I understand, but mod_rewrite is used to 'beautify' the URL rather than redirect to a new one. I'm still searching for a way of doing what you asked via mod_rewrite, just not sure there is one.

Comment: No worries, it's OK. I've accepted your answer, thanks for the extra info regarding mod_rewrite. Have a nice day! :)